# Getting around the max_file_uploads limit?

Tags: file-upload, limit, php, shared-hosting

I have an HTML form with a list of uploaded images and corresponding `input type="file"` fields.

As the list grows it begins to hit the max_file_uploads limit which, most often, cannot be modified on shared/mutual hosting.

What approach(es) could I take to get round this ?

P.S: Thought of staggered approach as can be done with populating a database but unclear on how I will do this at the moment.

Comment: @relentless That is one possibility but unfortunately this is seldom an option on shared (aka non dedicated) hosting. Forget to mention this detail.

Comment: May I suggest: http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a HTML5 or Flash uploader to upload one file at once. This way the limit will only be a limit for a single file. Your could try something like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

Answer (score 1):

change this line in your php.ini ... pass it the number of files you want to allow

max_file_uploads=50

Comment: Not a possibility unfortunately. Would be doable on dedicated hosting.

Comment: maybe this post helps then
http://www.webhostingzone.org/change-php-settings.html